# Implementation of WhereListIterator.ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In a piece of code like

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
IEnumerable<int> bar = foo.Where(x => x % 2 == 1);
```

`bar` is of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<int>` due to deferred execution. Since it implements `IEnumerable<int>` it is possible to convert it to a `List<int>`using `ToList()`. However, I have been unable to identify some parts of the code that is run when `ToList()` is called. I am using dotPeek as a decompiler and this is my first time attempting such a thing, so correct me if i made any mistakes on the way.

I will describe what I found so far below (All assemblies are Version 4.0.0.0):

1. `Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator<TSource>` is implemented in the file `Enumerable.cs` of the namespace `System.Linq` in the assembly `System.Core`. The class neither defines `ToList()` itself nor does it implement `IEnumerable<TSource>`. It implements `Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>` which is located in the same file. `Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>` does implement `IEnumerable<TSource>`.
2. `ToList()` is an extension mewthod that is also located in `Enumerable.cs`. All it  does is null checking and then calling the constructor of `List<TSource>` with its argument.
3. `List<T>` is defined in the file `List.cs` of the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` in the assembly `mscorlib`. The constructor that is called by `ToList()` has the signature `public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)`. It once again null checks and then casts the argument to `ICollection<T>`. If the collection has no elements, its creates a new list of an empty array, otherwise it uses the `ICollection.CopyTo()` method to create the new list.
4. `ICollection<T>` is defined in `mscorlib` \ `System.Collections.Generic` \ `ICollection.cs`. It implements `IEnumerable` in its generic and non-generic form.

This is where I am stuck. Neither `Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator<TSource>` nor `Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>` implement `ICollection`, so somewhere, a cast has to happen and I am unable to locate the code that is run when `CopyTo()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by the `as` operator. It's basically a safe cast. It's equivalent to this, but a bit faster:

```
MyEndType x = null;
if (MyVarWithAs is MyEndType) x = (MyEndType)MyVarWithAs;
```

Now, let's look at the code again now.

```
 public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      if (collection == null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
      ICollection<T> collection1 = collection as ICollection<T>;
      if (collection1 != null)
      {
        int count = collection1.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
          this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
        }
        else
        {
          this._items = new T[count];
          collection1.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
          this._size = count;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        this._size = 0;
        this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
        foreach (T obj in collection)
          this.Add(obj);
      }
    }
```

As you can see, in the `if` it checks if it's `null`. If it's `null`, it means that it is **not** an `ICollection<T>`, so *then it goes to the `else`*. All the `else` does is set everything to the default, and **then** adds everything in manually. When you pass in an `IEnumerable<T>` that is **not** an `ICollection<T>` (like in your example) it will go through the `else` path.

Answer (score 3):

This is the relevant part in the [`List<T>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) (ILSpy):

```
ICollection<T> collection2 = collection as ICollection<T>; // this won't succeed
if (collection2 != null) 
{
    int count = collection2.Count;
    this._items = new T[count];
    collection2.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
    this._size = count;
    return;
}
// this will be used instead
this._size = 0;
this._items = new T[4];
using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        this.Add(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

So you see that `collection as ICollection<T>;` tries to cast to `ICollection<T>`, if that works the efficient `CopyTo` will be used, otherwise the sequence will be enumerated entirely.

Your `WhereListIterator<int>` is a *query* and not a collection, so it cannot be casted to `ICollection<T>`, hence it will be enumerated.